# Use content_for to insert

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to insert my sign up form into the layout file using 'content_for' but i'm having some difficulty. The goal is to have the form in the file but I want it to be hidden. I will then use JQuery to make the form slideDown() on click.

I've consulted the following but I couldn't solve the problem:

[How can I use content_for to put something in :yield](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3984980/how-can-i-use-content-for-to-put-something-in-yield)

http://railscasts.com/episodes/8-layouts-and-content-for

The form I want to insert into the layout (Users/new.html.erb):

```
<% content_for :login do %>

  <%= form_for @user do |f| %>

# Rest of the form below
.
.
.

  <% end %>

<% end %>
```

In application.html.erb I have the following snippet in the body tag:

```
<%= yield :login %>
```

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Comment: What problem are you having?

Comment: I'm trying to insert my sign up form into the layout file using 'content_for' but I can't get it to work. Maybe there is something wrong with my syntax, not quite sure.

Answer (score 0):

Your syntax looks correct, so I can only assume something else is wrong.

Are you sure the correct layout is rendering? Put some other content in `application.html.erb` and look for it in the browser. Also put some other content in the `content_for` block in `users/new.html` besides the form to check that it's not specifically the `form` tag that's malrendering.

Have you tried inspecting the source?

Comment: What I decided to was just render a partial from application.html.erb. <%= render partial: 'users/form' %> Im not sure if this is the correct way to go about this but it works for now. Thank you for suggestions Jeriko, appreciate it!

Comment: I double checked and yes the correct layout is rendering. Everything I put into application.html.erb does show up in the browser. I put some other content into users/new.html and that content does not show up either. I checked the source and form is not present.

Comment: How about if you add `<%= yield %>` into `application.html.erb` and then replace the entire view `users/new.html` with `<h1>content</h1>`?